# How do I change the default folder for the Facebook app download location?

Tags: file-system, facebook, media-files

When I save a photo from the FB app, it gets saved to the Facebook folder $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/DCIM/Facebook/. I want to change this folder destination to my pictures folder $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/PICTURES/Facebook/. One would think this would be obvious for FB.

I've checked Android settings, Facebook app settings and Googled for both, but can't find anything certain. I'm not sure if it's a Facebook thing or a samsung thing. Here is a kicker for you; in a weird way when saving a meme from Memories in the FB app, it once in a while saves that picture, by default to Pictures/Facebook. For most of the time, pics get saved to DCIM/Facebook by default. As if FB can't make up its mind. Photos of which I'm talking about are all memes.

I managed to find and change the default location for my screenshots from $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/DCIM/Screenshots to $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/PICTURES/Screenshots in Android settings. And this got me thinking, can I do the same for my FB downloads folder?

I don't use FB for taking photos or videos. I'm not looking to move or sync my photos to another folder. I'm looking for a solution of changing the the folder destination like I did with the Screenshots folder. This would avoid having to move or sync my files to another folder altogether.

Samsung A13, Android 13

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't use that app. However you can try to sync images from that folder to another folder in your desired location, using an app like [folder sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite). You can configure it to delete images at source as also set up a schedule sync//It's an excellent app and I use it often to sync folders from cloud